# Installing Jenkins on Solaris SPARC

Tags: java, jenkins, solaris, coredump, sparc

I am trying to install Jenkins on a Solaris SPARC machine. I have Jenkins version 1.533 and the Java version 1.6.0_21. I executed "java -jar jenkins.war" to install Jenkins but got the following log and a core file was dumped.

```
java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: /home/hub/hudson/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
[Winstone 2013/09/30 13:56:31] - Beginning extraction from war file
hudson home directory: /home/hub/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
[Winstone 2013/09/30 13:56:35] - AJP13 Listener started: port=8009
[Winstone 2013/09/30 13:56:35] - HTTP Listener started: port=8080
Using one-time self-signed certificate
Sep 30, 2013 1:56:36 PM hudson.model.Hudson$5 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
[Winstone 2013/09/30 13:56:36] - Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 running: controlPort=disabled
Sep 30, 2013 1:56:38 PM hudson.model.Hudson$5 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Sep 30, 2013 1:56:38 PM hudson.model.Hudson$5 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Sep 30, 2013 1:56:38 PM hudson.model.Hudson$5 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Sep 30, 2013 1:56:38 PM hudson.model.Hudson$5 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Sep 30, 2013 1:56:38 PM hudson.model.Hudson$5 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Abort(coredump)
```

I am not sure if I am missing something or if something's not quite right with Jenkins and Solaris. Any ideas?

Comment: which version of Java do you have?

Comment: java version "1.6.0_21"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)

Comment: Jenkins uses the winstone servlet engine so you could try adding debug to your command `java -jar jenkins.war --debug 9` https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins and http://winstone.sourceforge.net/#commandLine. I suspect its missing a library or running out of heap space

Answer (score -1):

I had this same error on Solaris/Sparc 10 with Java 7 and 8. We installed Jenkins on a Sparc server with Solaris 11 and did not have the abort issue.

Workaround for Solaris 10 is located here.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29171

Comment: You mean her question ;-)